# Android SDK: Using the emulator to browse local websites

Tags: android-emulator, android-sdk

I'd love to be able to develop mobile websites on my **windows 7 pc** be able to see them instantly in mobile chrome/opera inside the android emulator.

I own an android phone, but uploading to my site and then browsing to it on my phone is just way too cumbersome.

I've downloaded the android sdk, but I have no idea how to start the emulator. I know nothing about java or android, and I can't make head nor tail of anything. Inside:

> adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130729/sdk/tools/

there are a bunch of executables that seem to suggest they launch the emulator, but they just launch the command line and nothing happens.

All I want to do is have a little graphic of an android phone floating on my screen, and be able to browse to my local websites inside its browser.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

From inside the emulator, you can access the localhost of the host machine by using the IP address 10.0.2.2 ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806220/how-to-connect-to-my-http-localhost-web-server-from-android-emulator-in-eclips)).

For further info about creating an AVD and using the emulator, check out the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/index.html).